# Purchased a cheap LED monitor with no power leads, how do I find the power leads?

Tags: led, display

[image: Cheap LED]

I just purchased a cheap TFT LED monitor and it has no power leads, how do I find where to soldier the power leads onto this unmarked circuit board?

Comment: What are you going to use to power it?

Comment: Ask the supplier?

Comment: It came with barrel plug, the supplier is a dropshipper that does not know their product

Comment: Cardinal rule:  *No datasheet* ⇒ *No sale*

Comment: It's a little late for that, but i'll keep it in mind next time.

Comment: Is there a part number for us to look at?

Comment: JWS-JX0701570d102A15 GP 14121203455 is all that is printed on the board

Comment: if you don't even know how to turn it on how are you supposed to display anything on it? my bet is on the big ass cap on the left side, 3V across it should do the trick.

Comment: unsolder the cap? and place the power leads on it?

Comment: Assuming you figure out how to power it, do the heck are you going to figure out how to send data to it?

Comment: there are vga cables

Comment: Connector next to the large Cap has labels. What do they say

Comment: You wonder why it was so cheap...?

Comment: Did that large cap at the top come like that? It seems fragile and badly constructed. I'm also wondering about the JST connector at the top that's at least two pins narrower than the silkscreen footprint.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two cheap linear regulator looking parts on the left.   It's a good bet that they share two nets, GND, and VCC input.  You should be able to figure out which one is GND, maybe you can trace it to the negative side of a capacitor, a gnd pin on the main IC, or maybe a tab on one of those connectors.   Then the other one is probably VCC input, and I bet you can trace it to one of those connectors.

You should check the regulators and see if there's any markings on them, then google for data sheets.   It's hard to see what they are with the picture.